# JSF Composite Component argument update

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

Hi i have created composite component which builds a dynamic form.
I pass 3 arguments to components backing bean. 2 of them are objects.

```
<p:outputPanel id="dynaForm"  >             
 <p:outputPanel rendered="#{formTest.dynamicForm!=null}" >
    Form in parent: #{formTest.dynamicForm.id}<br/>

    <cc:dynamicFormComponent 
      formObject="#{formTest.form}"
      formDataObject="#{formTest.recordObject}"
      mode="1"
    /> 

 </p:outputPanel>           
</p:outputPanel>
```

It works well when used statically, but when I try to dynamically change atribute `formObject` using selectOneMenu and update `dynaForm` panel, first time it builds a form but when i try to change form the attribute does not update, it remembers the first choice. This happens only with object attributes, if I use string it's changing normally. I output id of the form in the panel and in composite component and it seems that composite component doesn't want to percept the updated value.

Here is the base of the component code:

```
<cc:interface componentType="dynamicFormComponentGenerator" >
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
  Form in component: #{cc.attrs.formObject.id}
<cc:implementation>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was stateHelper problem, I stored these attributes on component initialize, in a backing bean using:

```
getStateHelper().put("formObject", formObject);
getStateHelper().put("formDataObject", formDataObject);
```

turns out it prevents them from changing on update until you clear all attributes from a State Helper before you try to set them again.

```
getStateHelper().remove("formObject");
getStateHelper().remove("formDataObject");
```